# Moving from one DNS provider to another

Tags: domains

I had registered with a particular DNS provider X and I have been unhappy with their services and now when the time for renewal came, I did not renew and I let it expire. I am hoping that once it is expired from this provider, I would be able to sign up for the same domain name from an alternative provider which I have tested and I am satisfied.

What kind of precautions should I take? The domain name is not a critical one, it is of a NGO and we prefer to own it again without any change in the name.

The information given by the expiry notice says

```
Domains can be renewed between 90 days before and 14 days after the expiry date. If domains are not renewed they will be removed from the account and set for deletion.
```

Should I wait for time till gets *deleted* at their end so that I can sign up for the same from another provider?

Comment: Most probably by that time your domain is gone in auction. I had a very nice domain name i lost it just like that :(

Answer (score 3):

Letting it expire is an extremely risky thing to do. Their is a high probability that you will lose that domain to domain squatters who will try to sell it back to you at a higher price, to companies that use expired domains to send traffic to paying sites, or networks of ad based sites. Once your site is lost the odds of you getting back are slim and even then if the opportunity to purchase back arises it will cost you *a lot* more then a simple renewal would cost.

A better idea would be to renew it with your current registrar and then transfer it to a new one. That way you maintain ownership of the domain through the entire process.

Comment: Thanks John for the information. I talked to the Current provider and he advised me the same. He said that once expired, he wont able to transfer to the new one, and he wanted me to renew with them for minimal period (1 year) and when it is active transfer it to the other name provider.

Comment: @Senith - take the renewal and just transfer it immediately. Generally when you do the transfer to the new registrar the new registrar won't charge you anything